# Rational homotopy groups of unordered configuration spaces of the torus

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Is there any computations or investigation about the rational homotopy groups of unordered configuration spaces of the torus?
Any help is welcome

Comment: It's unclear what one ought to mean by the rational $\pi_1$ of a space if that space isn't nilpotent. Are you only interested in the higher homotopy?

Comment: Hi MyIsmail. I suspect there is not much work out there on the rational homotopy groups of these spaces, because they are aspherical (so $\pi_i(X)\otimes\mathbb{Q}=0$ for $i>1$) and the fundamental group (which in the two-point case looks to be some extension of $\mathbb{Z}^2\times F_2$ by $\mathbb{Z}_2$) seems not to be nilpotent.